# OpenGL Drawing "axis"

Tags: c, opengl

For a piece of coursework we have to build a working model of the solar system. I have mine implemented with planets (spheres), but we also have to draw the axis of the planet as a line above and below.

I am finding that using GL_LINES doesn't seem to be working, presumably because of the scale of this project (the radius of the planets is 139000000+).

Simplified example:

```
void drawAxis(int n)
{
  /* Draws the axis for body "n" */
  glColor3f(1.0,0.0,0.0);
  glBegin(GL_LINES);
    glVertex3f(0, bodies[n].radius, 0);
    glVertex3f(0, bodies[n].radius*2, 0);
  glEnd();

  glColor3f(0.0,1.0,0.0);
  glBegin(GL_LINES);
    glVertex3f(0, -bodies[n].radius, 0);
    glVertex3f(0, -bodies[n].radius*2, 0);
  glEnd();
}

void drawBody(int n)
{

  if(n==0) {
    /* Draws body "n" */
    //glRotatef(bodies[n].axis_tilt, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0);

    //Scale and position
    glTranslatef(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glScalef(SCALE,SCALE,SCALE); //why already scaled? 

    //Axis
    drawAxis(n);   

    //r g b - colour (red, green, blue)
    glColor3f(bodies[n].r,bodies[n].g,bodies[n].b);

    //radius - size of body (km)
    glutSolidSphere (bodies[n].radius/SCALE, 50, 50);   
  }
}
```

Draws:

[image: SolarSystem]

Am I missing something critical here?

What is the best "work around" for drawing axis on this sphere?

Comment: "the radius of the planets is 139000000+" Why? Why isn't the radius of the planet 1.39? Scale is OpenGL is what *you* want it to be. It's not meters, centimeters, feet, miles, kilometers, or whatever. It is exactly what you want it to be. So pick your scale so that it makes things easiest for you.

Comment: I thought it simple didn't matter, so to make it easy with my datafile kept it at KM

Comment: Hi Pez, as Nicol says, the scale is causing the problem. As you've said your self, the line doesn't really have a 'width' so to speak, but that means you're rendering something infinitely small when trying to fit several hundred thousand km into one camera shot. It's not surprising than an infinitely thin line isn't displayed ;)

Comment: Pez, have you tried calling glLineWidth() before you draw the axis?  You could pass in some larger value and see what happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
glScalef(SCALE,SCALE,SCALE); //why already scaled? 

...

glutSolidSphere (bodies[n].radius/SCALE, 50, 50);
```

This makes no sense. Why would you apply a uniform scale, only to then divide your sphere's scale by it, thus undoing the scale? Wouldn't it make more sense to have no scale at all and just use `bodies[n].radius`?

This is the source of your problem. See, you undo your unnecessary scale when you draw your sphere, but you *don't* undo it when you draw your axes. If you take out the unnecessary scale, there's a better chance that it will work.

Comment: That doesn't explain why the axis aren't there surely? I was trying to scale before I realised the line wouldn't be affected by the scale (as it's just two point)

Comment: Removing this doesn't seem to change the problem, thanks for the idea though

Comment: @PezCuckow: Yes it makes a difference. Because you didn't did that counterscale on your axes, they will not be located on the sphere's surface. Either use only glScale with unit radius, or don't use glScale but apply the scale on the geometry data.